# Code review software with ticketing system and in-line code editor

Tags: software-development, issue-tracker, code-review

I am looking for (preferably offline or at least quite secure) code review software that includes a ticketing system (where one can pick up and edit projects) and a code editor for in-line code editing and commenting (mainly Stata, Matlab, Python, and R).

In the ticketing system I would like (but is not necessary):

- email (or other?) notification system for changes in ticket status and weekly updates
- incentive for editing code (something like reputation here on StackExchange)

In the code review system I would like:

- syntax highlighting

I would also like to have a parallel forum and wiki for code discussion, but those do not necessarily have to be included in the software here, it would just be a nice extra.

**Edit for clarity:**

- The service must work on Windows
- It does not need to be free, I am looking for as many viable options as possible regardless of cost

I am looking for a standalone platform, so it does not have to be integrated with GitHub or any other version control software. In our specific use many different projects will be started with only two or three edit cycles for each.

Comment: Any operating system? Grratis, or do you have a budget? Should it work with any particular version vcontrol system? Plesae read [ask] and help us to help you

Comment: @Mawg, thanks for the suggestion, hopefully the edit helps clarify what I am looking for

Comment: Have you looked at either Gitlab or Github Enterprise? There's also Redmine

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for [ReviewBoard](https://www.reviewboard.org/).

- Interfaces with multiple version control systems
- Syntax highlighted code, *(in 300 languages),* in diffs
- Smart handling of indentation changes
- Documentation review as well as code
- Moved code detection
- Issue Tracking
- Lots of notification options
- Lots of reporting options

[image]

Comment: Looks good (+1). I don't immediately see from the site wherther it is gratis, but I also don't see an option to purchase. Do you know?

Comment: @Mawg https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/faq/ - it is MIT licenced, 100% Free.

Comment: I will be looking into it in more detail; we could certianly use something similar here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SteveBarnes, I will be checking into this software as well, it even looks like it can be hosted locally which is a plus for me!